# Passing a variable to a Servlet via <a href>

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I want to pass a variable from one JSP: "liste" to a Servlet"Fiche1ControllerServlet" so that i can do an HQL request there. But before executing the request, i try to display the value i'm getting from the first JSP to test if that works, but unfortunately it doesn't works. Have i forgot to add something in my code? Help me plz!

liste.jsp

```
<c:forEach var="projet" items="${listProject}">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${projet[2]}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${projet[1]}" /></td>

                    <td><c:out value="${projet[3]}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${projet[4]}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${projet[5]}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${projet[6]}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${projet[7]}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${projet[8]}" /></td>
                    <td><a href="Fiche1ControllerServlet?valeur=${projet[2]}">
                            Accéder aux détails</a></td>
```

Fiche1ControllerServlet.java

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import dao.ActeurDAO;

public class Fiche1ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String val=request.getParameter("valeur");


        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

         try {

                System.out.println(val);
                getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/ajoutacteur.jsp").forward(request, response);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }}
```

Comment: A link won't send a POST request, but a GET request. So the doPost() method won't be called. doGet() will be.

Comment: I change it to doGet, but i'm getting the 404Http error, "La ressource demandée n'est pas dsponible" . In the link should i keep the name of the servlet or the path of the JSP?

Comment: @ JB Nizet and when i changed it to {<td><a href="fiche1.jsp?valeur=${projet[2]}">} i got nothing displayed!!

Comment: You will need to expand on "but unfortunately it doesn't works." What is the value of  request.getParameter("valeur")? Null, Empty String, Something else???

Comment: @Alan Hay, i mean it displays nothing in the console, normally it should display val in the console.

Comment: The problem is that i wasn't calling the servlet with the name that i defined for it in file web.xml!! Thank all for your efforts!